# angularjs: how to convert values in table based on currency selection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, localization, angularjs-ng-repeat, globalization

I have one table which has amount column. I have one currency dropdown list above  which has all the currencies of the world, on selection of any currency my amount should convert through exchange rate and show it on table.

[image]

I am facing couple of challenges over my approach:

1. The default amount field in objec should not change in that case I have add fake column to just show the converted amount. is it right?
2. how can I make use of localization and globalization.

I have less idea about it if anyone has faced anything please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a filter method:

```
.filter('currency', [function() {
    return function(amount, currency) {
        return amount.currency * currency.exchangeRate;
    }
}]);
```

and for your template

```
<div ng-bind="amount | currency : currentSelectedCurrency"></div>
```

This wouldn't change the value of the amount, just the way it is displayed.